# What are the advantages of storing gem sources in vendor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Storing gem sources in vendor makes deployment slower since the size of the folder is larger, wondering what are the advantages of doing this?

Any other disadvantages other than deployment gets larger?

Comment: I'm curious, what *advantage* is there?

Comment: well you can have different gem versions per web app on the same server without conflicting no?

Comment: As someone mentioned below, this is the purpose of **[Bundler](http://gembundler.com/)**

Answer (score 0):

Vendoring your gems was relevant before two changes in Rails:

- Sometime in the Rails 2.X series `config.gem` was added to the environment files to allow management of gem version.
- When 3.0 came out, there was Bundler, which allowed even better control of gem version.

Before this the only way to guarantee that gem versions were fixed was to vendor them, and distribute them with the rest of the app, allowing all members of a development team to always have the correct gems and versions. For more on whys and hows, have a read of this [Chris Wanstrath article from 2007](http://errtheblog.com/posts/50-vendor-everything).

Comment: but say you have 10 web apps on the same server, how can you use the same gem, but different versions on the apps? e.g. some use version 1.1 and others might use 1.5

Comment: Vendoring, config.gem and Bundler all allow you to have different gem versions for different applications on the same host.